# Corona SDK, Timer pause and resume does not work?

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk

My timer pause and resume does not work? it has a logical error which said WARNING:timer.resume(timerID)ignored b/c was not paused. Any idea? Should i add add or remove listener to remove to stop the transition of the timer?

```
local timerEnabled = true --  Stops or allows our countdown timer       
local touchEnabled = false      

local delay_timer               
local timer_trans   -- transition of my timerbar           

local timer_rect      --display object          
local timer_bar        -- display object       

function pauseGame(  )
    if (timerEnabled==false) then
            timer.pause(timer_bar)
            answer_rect:removeEventListener( "touch", buttonTouched )

    elseif (timerEnabled==true) then
            timer.resume(timer_bar)    
            answer_rect:addEventListener( "touch", buttonTouched )

    end
end


local pauseButtonPress = function( event )
    pauseGame()
end

        timer_rect = display.newRect(uiGroup, _W*0.5, question_rect.y+question_rect.height, _W, 50 )
        timer_rect.anchorY = 0
        timer_rect:setFillColor(0,0.3,0.7)

    if timerEnabled == true then 
        timer_bar = display.newRect(uiGroup, 0, timer_rect.y+timer_rect.height-20, _W, 35)
        timer_bar.anchorX = 0 
        timer_bar:setFillColor(0.8,1,1)
    end

        pauseButton= widget.newButton{       
        defaultFile = "images1/Buttons/Pause.png",
        overFile= "images1/Buttons/Resume.png",
        onRelease = pauseButtonPress,
    }
        pauseButton.x = 100
        pauseButton.y = 90
        pauseButton.xScale = .6
        pauseButton.yScale = .6
```

Answer (score 0):

timer.pause() and timer.resume() should receive a timerID as param, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
local function listener( event )
    print( "listener called" )
end

timer1 = timer.performWithDelay( 2000, listener )  -- wait 2 seconds

-- sometime later...
local result = timer.pause( timer1 )
print( "Time remaining is " .. result )
```

More information about [timer.pause()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/pause.html) and  [timer.resume()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/resume.html)  you may find in [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html).